# Crystal reports - server and database

Tags: crystal-reports, report, connection-string

Im using visual studio 2010 + Sql Server 2008.

Im trying to show my reports using CR.. well when i try to use the system in my local machine, everything is ok.

I use store procedures to create reports.

The issue appears when i deploy the system in another PC.. A message appears asking for:

Server: // RETRIEVES ORIGINAL Server(Local)// Its not Correct i need to get Client Server
Database: // RETRIEVES ORIGINAL DB(Local)// Its not Correct i need to get Client DB
Username: I don't use any user , what user ?
Password: I don't use any password, what password?

i saw another solutions, but i can't find what's the data that i must use in Username or password. i use Windows autenthication to login to sql..

Thanks.

Regards.

Edit.. that's my code.. i can't use parameters, i don't receive any error. but system dont recognize the parameter that i send...

Dim NuevoReporte As New CReportNotaPorUsuario
            Dim contenido As String
            Dim ReportPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\CReportNotaPorUsuario.rpt"

```
        Dim ConexionCR As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()
        contenido = Servicios.Funciones_Auxiliares.LeerArchivo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\configuracion.txt")
        ConexionCR.ServerName = Servicios.Funciones_Auxiliares.TextoEntreMarcas(contenido, "<server>", "</server>")
        ConexionCR.DatabaseName = Servicios.Funciones_Auxiliares.TextoEntreMarcas(contenido, "<catalog>", "</catalog>")
        ConexionCR.IntegratedSecurity = True

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportPath


        'NuevoReporte.SetParameterValue("@cod_usuario", cbousuario.SelectedValue)

        Dim field1 As ParameterField = Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo(0)
        Dim val1 As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
        val1.Value = cbousuario.SelectedValue
        field1.CurrentValues.Add(val1)


        SetDBLogonForReport(ConexionCR)
```

Comment: The user account on the other PC may not have permission to access the database.

Comment: But.. the Server and DB that the system retrieves is not the correct, because i get original(OLD) connection string. I need to get the actual (Client PC) connection string. thx for your answer

Comment: In your question you say that it retrieves the original server and database but asks for username and password, which you don't have. Now you are saying it's not retrieving the correct server and database?

Comment: Yep, sry if i not explain my issue correctly...

It retrieves the original (but not correct) server, i need to get the client server. also i need to know whats the data that i need to use in Username and password fields.

Comment: So you have two different databases? One on the development side and one on the production side. You have to make sure when you deploy your solution to specify the production server, not the development server.

Comment: im not declaring server or db, i don't know whats the correct steps to declare the sv name and db name. i  only tried using Connectioninfo.servername = "Client DB" and Connectioninfo.database= " Client DB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have separate servers and databases between the development and production environment. You need to make sure when you deploy your VS solution that the production server and database get referenced, not the development server and database.
There are some tutorials out there that can help you find a way to achieve this. Check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193254(v=vs.100).aspx

[Visual Studio 2010 Database Project Deploy to Different Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597553/visual-studio-2010-database-project-deploy-to-different-environments)

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/customizing-database-deployments-for-multiple-environments

EDIT: This seems to have evolved into a different issue than originally stated in the question. To dynamically get the connection string for CR from the text file, you will have to read teh text file first and put server name and database name into variables. Reading a text file, you can use something like `string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\File.txt");` but you will need to extract server name and database name into variables. Then in order to use the variables in your connection string you use `ConnectionInfo.Servername = variable1;` and `ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = variable2`.

Comment: My problem is that the solution will be deployed on a "client" machine, in fact this is a university project..

I do not know which will be the destination machine, I will execute the script and installed with the user name you want on the server that the user wants. The user enters the server and the database on a screen, and written to a text file. The system reads the text file and get the connection string. But not for the reports, only for the system, I need to get crystal reports server and the name of the database that text file

Comment: Then you need to use variables in your connection string and at the time the report gets run, the connection string needs to retrieve the values from the text file. This is turning into a much different problem from what you stated in your original question.

Comment: I admit that I did not explain in the best way. Then the problem is, how do I change the connection string that uses crystal reports? Try using connectioninfo.servername unsuccessfully ... thank you!

Comment: See edit in my original answer. Do some research on how to read a text file and get certain values out. I don't know how your file will be structured. But if the user input of database and server happens in your project, you can just use the values of the textboxes instead of parsing through the text file.

Comment: i can retrieve both values (server and DB)but when i run the solution the same error appears...

Comment: Please post the full error message and append it to your original question.

Comment: i dont understand you.. DSN = Datasource name? where?

Comment: Your error in my opinion can have 3 causes: 1. You are trying to connect to a database as a user that doesn't have permission 2. You are trying to connect to a database via DSN that is not installed on the PC 3. Your database driver needs to be updated. I think at this point you need to post the code you are using to try and connect to the database.